# Настройка порта USB (FLOW CONTROL)

Tags: c++, usb, железо

Помогите настроить порт USB
DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE
0x00

DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE
0x01

DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE
0x02
Есть три режима и три варианта выбора в программе 
XON/XOFF 
Nardware
none

Что с чем сопоставить 
я предполагаю None это DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE 
hardware  DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE

XON/XOFF  DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE

Может я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: О каком USB на каком железе  в каком режиме, на каком языке программирования идёт речь?

Comment: USB термо-принтер  на с++cli.      Есть комбобокс в нем три значения XON/XOFF Nardware none  мне нужно сопоставить их с DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE 0x00

DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE 0x01

DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE 0x02 что бы сознать подкючение с выбраным параметром

Comment: в таком случае необходимы более точные данные о вашей аппаратной части и крайне желательны исходники/ что не получается.

Comment: Структура DCB имеет в себе fDtrControl (Flow control)  он имеет два режима DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE 0x01 и DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE 0x02                                                                    а в программе есть комбобокс в нем XON/XOFF и Nardware       при выборе должно инициализироватся fDtrControl. Вопрос  при выборе XON/XOFF какой знаечение должно быть записано в fDtrControl ?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич у меня почему то показало c++11, поэтому отклонил правку. Теперь вижу, что не так, сорри.

Answer (score -1):

```
DCB SetDCB;
GetCommState(ConDevice, &SetDCB);
SetDCB.DCBlength = sizeof(SetDCB);
SetDCB.BaudRate = System::Convert::ToInt64(BaudRateCB->SelectedItem);
SetDCB.fBinary = TRUE;
SetDCB.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
SetDCB.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
if (FlowControlCB->SelectedIndex == 1) {
    SetDCB.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
}
if (FlowControlCB->SelectedIndex == 0) {
    SetDCB.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
}
SetDCB.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;
SetDCB.fNull = FALSE;
SetDCB.fRtsControl = 0x01;
SetDCB.fAbortOnError = FALSE;
SetDCB.ByteSize = System::Convert::ToInt64(DataBitsCB->SelectedItem);
SetDCB.Parity = ParityCB->SelectedIndex;
SetDCB.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
SetCommState(ConDevice, &SetDCB);
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос, так как сам вопрос является слишком общим, без конкретики.